# Samsung A71 unable to read outgoing messages with telephony provider

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, telephonymanager

Unable to read all sent and received messages using Telephony Content Provider. I am using Samsung A71 Device, I am using Telephony service to read all messages

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
       String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
       String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
       sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);  

}
```

But I can only get incoming messages I cannot get any outgoing messages with telephony service.

I have tried using the [easy-content-providers](https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers) library, it is also showing only incoming messages.
https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

How can I get outgoing messages in Samsung A71? Can someone help me solving this issue?

Comment: `/inbox` would seem to be specific to incoming messages. Have you tried using `Telephony.Sms.Outbox.CONTENT_URI`?

Comment: In my case I need both incoming and outgoing messages, anyways I tried using this `Telephony.Sms.Outbox.CONTENT_URI` I am having 0 results, having this issue with Samsung A71 device only, other devices are retrieving all messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I came to know that the Samsung A71 Default Messages app is not using android Message formats while storing the messages in the device, that is the reason I cannot able read sent messages on the A71 device.

**How did I know this?**
I have installed Some other messaging app from the play store, on that app also I cannot see the sent messages, I can only see the incoming messages, Thus I realized the issue is with Samsung messaging app.

Appreciated any can provide another working solution for this device.